# OmniORB Build with Python

Tags: python, python-3.8, omniorb

I have downloaded omniORB 4.3.1 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/omniorb/files/omniORB/omniORB-4.3.1/omniORB-4.3.1.tar.bz2/download. After decompression we got READMEWIN32.txt inside folder. The Steps involves calling "make export" command after setting the Cygwin and python path in vs 2022.

I manually tried to build the omniORB after following the README. It is successful inside vs 2022 cmd(x64 Native tools).

When I tried to automate the Build process through python, I stuck up with following error(This happens after make export command):

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/apurusharthi/Desktop/omniORB-4.3.1/src/tool/omkdepend'
+ rm -f omkdepend.exe
+ ../../../bin/x86_win32/linkwrapper -gnuwin32 -out:omkdepend.exe -nologo -manifest -DEBUG -PDB:omkdepend.exe.pdb -libpath:../../../lib/x86_win32 include.o main.o parse.o pr.o cppsetup.o ifparser.o gnuwin32.o advapi32.lib
link: unknown option -- o
Try 'link --help' for more information.
link -out:omkdepend.exe -nologo -manifest -DEBUG -PDB:omkdepend.exe.pdb -libpath:..\..\..\lib\x86_win32 include.o main.o parse.o pr.o cppsetup.o ifparser.o gnuwin32.o advapi32.lib
+ mt.exe '/outputresource:omkdepend.exe;#1' /manifest omkdepend.exe.manifest
Microsoft (R) Manifest Tool

Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

All rights reserved.


omkdepend.exe.manifest : general error c1010070: Failed to load and parse the manifest. The system cannot find the file specified.

make[2]: *** [dir.mk:22: omkdepend.exe] Error 31
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/alpha/Desktop/omniORB-4.3.1/src/tool/omkdepend'
make[1]: *** [dir.mk:22: export] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/alpha/Desktop/omniORB-4.3.1/src/tool'
make: *** [dir.mk:26: export] Error 2

Build System Info: OmniORBBuild Critical Error: Installation Failed
```

Can you please help me on this? Python 3.8 is calling "make export" using Subprocess module

Comment: Do you also run your Python script from a VS cmd prompt? For the build with VS to be successful, the environment variables in `vcvarsall.bat` need to be set. If that's not the case, you need to run that batch file first.